# GmsBarcodeScanner camera view stays black

Tags: android, google-play-services, barcode-scanner

I've implemented the google services GmsBarcodeScanner and it did work a couple of days ago. Now when I open it, it will show the colored border of the the scanner and the rest of the UI just fine, but the actual camera feed stays black.
I don't know if it's related, but the logs show the following:

```
MSHandlerLifeCycle  removeMultiSplitHandler: no exist. decor=DecorView@4e64279[GmsBarcodeScanningDelegateActivity]
OpenGLRenderer  setSurface called with nullptr
OpenGLRenderer  setSurface() destroyed EGLSurface
OpenGLRenderer  destroyEglSurface
WindowManager   win=Window{3ada8d8 u0 my.app.bundle/com.google.mlkit.vision.codescanner.internal.GmsBarcodeScanningDelegateActivity} destroySurfaces: appStopped=true cleanupOnResume=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false win.mViewVisibility=4 caller=com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:6428 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:6409 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.notifyAppStopped:6473 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.activityStopped:7060 com.android.server.wm.ActivityClientController.activityStopped:258 android.app.IActivityClientController$Stub.onTransact:613 com.android.server.wm.ActivityClientController.onTransact:136
```

```
GmsBarcodeScanner scanner = GmsBarcodeScanning.getClient(this);
scanner.startScan()
        .addOnSuccessListener(
                barcode -> {
                    // Task completed successfully
                    String rawValue = barcode.getRawValue();
                    Log.d("scanner", "BARCODE Scanner: success '" + rawValue + "'");
                    this.onBarcodeReceived(rawValue);
                })
        .addOnCanceledListener(
                () -> {
                    // Task canceled
                    Log.d("scanner", "BARCODE Scanner: canceled");
                })
        .addOnFailureListener(
                e -> {
                    // Task failed with an exception
                    Log.e("scanner", "BARCODE Scanner: failed", e);
                });
```

I already did implement `ModuleInstallClient` to check wether the service is downloaded and available and it works. It does open, it just doesn't show the camera feed. I also tried to scan a code, which worked a couple of days ago to check if it's just not showing the image, but actually processing it, but no luck. The camera app on the same phone works just fine, so it's not a mechanical issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.